# How to sum the values of multiple items in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

I'd like to sum the values of multiple objects.

I have an array of example 3 items, this varies and can be any number.

```
_items: 
0: {...}
1: {...}
2: {...}
```

Each of these item then has the following data:

```
0: 
dayOfYear: 357
dayOfWeek: 4
noOfUnits: "11"
_id: "12345"
_owner: "12345"
_createdDate: "Thu Dec 23 2021"
year: 2021
_updatedDate: "Thu Dec 23 2021"
week: 51
userId: "12345"
type: "Type 1"
```

I'd like to add the values of the `noOfUnits` variable. So for example in item 0 value is `11`, item 1 is `2` and item 2 is `5`. The total would become `18`. This is not limited to 3 items but varies according to the number of items pulled from a database.

Thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: Can you also include any code you've tried so far?

Comment: This is just a simple map and reduce operation: `_items.map(x => parseInt(x.noOfUnits)).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: const reducer = (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue.noOfUnits); 
console.log(_items.reduce(reducer, 0));

Comment: You can use a `for ... in` loop to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it

```
        const results = [
            {noOfUnits: "11"},
            {noOfUnits: "2"},
            {noOfUnits: "5"},
        ]
        console.log(results.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.noOfUnits), 0))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I downvoted because this is a very common question. Rather than create multiple low quality questions, it's preferred that we close duplicate questions and consolidate them into a single question. Such questions should not be answered until they are proven not to be a duplicate.

Comment: Or we can just help people when they ask for it, but opinions can differ I guess

Comment: Unfortunately, [it's not just my opinion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). The Stack Exchange network is a **Q&A** site, not a forum or help site. As such, if a question already exists then it should be consolidated so that a single source of truth exists.

Comment: @skara9 https://gfycat.com/enragedlightcoelacanth

Comment: @skara9 the point is that we should not be encouraging people to answer questions that are obvious candidates for duplication. I get that people are trying to help OP, but there are a plethora of questions that would solve their problem. People should prioritize guiding askers towards those master questions rather than fragmenting knowledge.